# how to separate a column into multiple columns and change the results from characters to numbers

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

[image]

##id##        ##initiativen##

1     abc          2a
2     cde          2b
3     efd           a
4     geh           c
5    jytd          5v
6 jydjytd           e

Hello, I have something similar to this, just a lot bigger and I was wondering which is the most efficient way to divide the column initiativen into two columns, one containing the numbers (2,2,5,4) and one containing the letters or the blank space. it has to be a general formula as the data frame I need to apply it too is quite big. The letters correspond to a particular initiative number but the first initiative number is not indicated and "a" correspond to initiative number 2.

I would love it to look like something like that with the letters substituted by numbers (blank=1, a=2, b=3 etc..)

```
id    initiativen question
abc        2         2
cde        3         2
efd        2         N/A
geh        4         N/A
jytd       23        5
jydjytd    6         N/A
bfdhslbf   1         3
```

I have tried to use "separate" but it doesn't really work and doesn't solve the problem of the first initiative having no corresponding letter.
Any help or suggestion would be extremely welcomed and helpful.

Thank you so much:)

Comment: Why did you remove your actual sample data and posted a screenshot instead? That's not useful. Please edit and include sample data.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following `tidyverse` solution?

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    separate(initiativen, into = c("p1", "p2"), sep = "(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])") %>%
    mutate(
        initiativen = case_when(
            str_detect(p1, "[a-z]") ~ p1,
            str_detect(p2, "[a-z]") ~ p2),
        question = case_when(
            str_detect(p1, "[0-9]") ~ p1,
            str_detect(p2, "[0-9]") ~ p2)) %>%
    mutate(initiativen = ifelse(is.na(initiativen), 1, match(initiativen, letters) + 1)) %>%
    select(-p1, -p2)
#       id initiativen question
#1     abc           2        2
#2     cde           3        2
#3     efd           2     <NA>
#4     geh           4     <NA>
#5    jytd          23        5
#6 jydjytd           6     <NA>
#7 vbdjfkb           1        4
```

Note that the warning can be safely ignored as it stems from the missing fields when `separate`ing.

Explanation: We use a positive look-behind and look-ahead to split entries in `initiativen` into two parts `p1` and `p2`; we then fill `initiativen` and `question` with entries from `p1` or `p2` depending on whether they contain a number `"[0-9]"` or a character `"[a-z]"`; convert characters to numbers with `match(initiativen, letters)` and finally clean the `data.frame`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "       id initiativen
1     abc          2a
2     cde          2b
3     efd           a
4     geh           c
5    jytd          5v
6 jydjytd           e
7 vbdjfkb          4", row.names = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
# Step one
    setDT(df)
df[, ":="(
      question  = gsub("[a-z]", "", initiativen),
      initiativen = match(gsub("[0-9]", "", initiativen), letters, nomatch = 0) + 1L
    )
   ]
df
        id initiativen question
1:     abc           2        2
2:     cde           3        2
3:     efd           2         
4:     geh           4         
5:    jytd          23        5
6: jydjytd           6         
7: vbdjfkb           1        4

# Then some tidying
df[, question := ifelse(nzchar(question), question, NA)]

df
        id initiativen question
1:     abc           2        2
2:     cde           3        2
3:     efd           2     <NA>
4:     geh           4     <NA>
5:    jytd          23        5
6: jydjytd           6     <NA>
7: vbdjfkb           1        4
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c("abc", "cde", "efd", "geh", "jytd", "jydjytd", "vbdjfkb"),
  initiativen = c("2a", "2b", "a", "c", "5v", "e", "4"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

**Edit**

Can also be done in one step:

```
df[, question := gsub("[a-z]", "", initiativen)
   ][, ":="(
      question = ifelse(nzchar(question), question, NA),
      initiativen = match(gsub("[0-9]", "", initiativen), letters, nomatch = 0) + 1L
    )
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second column you can use regular expression to only keep numeric values:

```
df$initiativen <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", df$initiativen)
```